# how to limit a variable to zero on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, while-loop, zero

I have started making a new game on python and have it so if either player1 or player2's health goes to zero or below, the code ends, but i do not want to display that the player has for example, -12 health at the end. Here is the code:

```
player1 = 50
player2 = 50
while player1 >= 0 or player2 >= 0:
    import random

    slash = random.randint(5, 9)
    stab = random.randint(1, 15)
    swing = random.randint(15, 20)
    heal = random.randint(10, 15)
    a = [slash, stab, swing]
    ai = random.choice(a)
    hit1 = input("Press 1 2 3 or 4")
    if hit1 == "1":
        print("You dealt " + str(slash))
        player2 = player2 - slash
        print("Player 2 now has " + str(player2))
    if hit1 == "2":
        print("You dealt " + str(stab))
        player2 = player2 - stab
        print("Player 2 now has " + str(player2))
    if hit1 == "3":
        print("You dealt " + str(swing))
        player2 = player2 - swing
        print("Player 2 now has " + str(player2))
    if hit1 == "4":
        print("You healed by " + str(heal))
        player2 = player1 + heal
        print("Player 1 now has " + str(player1))
    hit2 = print("player 2 has dealt " + str(ai))
    player1 = player1 - ai
    print("player1 is now on " +str(player1))
```

Comment: instead of `str(player1)` use `str(max(0, player1))`

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [`max`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/max) function in python.

for your relevant lines:

```
 player2 = max(player2 - slash, 0)

 player2 = max(player2 - stab, 0)

 player2 = max(player2 - swing, 0)

 player1 = max(player1 - ai, 0)
```

moreover, you need to change your while condition:

```
while player1 > 0 or player2 > 0:
```

**edit**:

```
player1 = 50
player2 = 50
while player1 > 0 and player2 > 0:
    import random

    slash = random.randint(5, 9)
    stab = random.randint(1, 15)
    swing = random.randint(15, 20)
    heal = random.randint(10, 15)

    hit_number_to_hit_type = {'1': slash,
                              '2': stab,
                              '3': swing}
    a = [slash, stab, swing]
    ai = random.choice(a)
    hit1 = input("Press 1 2 3 or 4\n")
    if "1" <= hit1 <= "3":
        hit = hit_number_to_hit_type[hit1]
        print("You dealt " + str(hit))
        player2 = max(player2 - hit, 0)
        print("Player 2 now has " + str(player2))
    if hit1 == "4":
        print("You healed by " + str(heal))
        player1 += heal
        print("Player 1 now has " + str(player1))
    hit2 = print("player 2 has dealt " + str(ai))
    player1 = max(player1 - ai, 0)
    print("player1 is now on " + str(player1))
```

Comment: I have tried this however my while loop is now not breaking once they hit 0

Comment: you have a bug in this line :         player2 = player1 + heal

i think it should be player1 += heal, or player2+= heal

Comment: @reece_crockford added a complete and improved code. note that the while condition is fixed too

Comment: I meant to have the line as: player1 = player1 + heal